# Getting the below error after adding redux to my code

Tags: reactjs

```
./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.legacy-esm.js 331:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (331:12)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     return false;
|   }
>   if (cache?.has(value)) return false;
|   const entries = getEntries != null ? getEntries(value) : Object.entries(value);
|   const hasIgnoredPaths = ignoredPaths.length > 0;
```